# Impresión en impresara de 80mm

Tags: javascript, impresora

necesito imprimir una tabla en una impresora de 80 mm,necesito que le aplique los bordes a todos los costados,sin embargo, solo lo hace a la izquierda y derecha mi código es el siguiente:

```js
const $btnPrint = document.querySelector("#btnPrint");
$btnPrint.addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.print();
});
```

```css
* {
    font-size: 7px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

td,th,tr,table {
    border-top-style: solid 1px;
    border-right-style: solid 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid 1px;
    border-left-style: solid 1px;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-left-color: #333;
    border-right-color: #333;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.description,
th.description {
    width: 75px;
    max-width: 75px;
    
    
}

td.quantity,
th.quantity {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

td.price,
th.price {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.ticket {
    width: 160px;
    margin: auto;

}

img {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

@media print {
    .hidden-print,
    .hidden-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #060201;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/imprimir/style.css">
        
        <title>CUOTA TOTAL</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
    font-size: 7px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
}

td,th,tr,table {
    border-top-style: solid 1px;
    border-right-style: solid 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid 1px;
    border-left-style: solid 1px;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-left-width: thin;
    border-left-color: #333;
    border-right-color: #333;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.description,
th.description {
    width: 75px;
    max-width: 75px;
    
    
}

td.quantity,
th.quantity {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

td.price,
th.price {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.ticket {
    width: 160px;
    margin: auto;

}

img {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

@media print {
    .hidden-print,
    .hidden-print * {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #060201;
    width: 100%;
  } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ticket">
           <!-- <img src="./logo.png" alt="Logo">-->
            <p class="centered"></p>
            
            <div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="description">Cliente</td>
  <td class="description" style="text-align:right;margin-left:5px;"> Horacio<br>444567</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</div>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="centered">
    <tr>
   
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
     <td class="description">ID de la apuesta</td>
    <td class="description" style="text-align:right;">124533</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</div>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
   
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="description">Fecha</td>
  <td class="description" style="text-align:right;">24-05-2023</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</div>
<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
   
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
      <td class="description" style="text-align:left;">Tipo de apuesta</td>
  <td class="description" style="text-align:right;">Individual</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</div>
<?php
if(!empty($categoriaarr)){ ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">

 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="font-size: 8px;">
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="description" style="font-size: 8px;text-align: left;">Categoría</th>
<th class="description" style="font-size: 8px;text-align: right;">Evento</th>
<!--<th class="description">Cuota</th>
<th class="description">Valor apostado</th>
<th class="description">Total</th>-->

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
        
<tr>
  <td style="">1X2</td>
  <td style="text-align: right;">Bayern munchen vs Real Madrid</td>
  <!--<td><?= $cuota; ?></td>
  <td><?= $monto; ?></td>
  <td><?= $total; ?></td>-->
  
 </tr>
 
 </tbody>

</table>

</div>
<!--SEGUNDA ITERACIÓN -->

 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <!--<th class="description">Categoría</th>
<th class="description">Evento</th>-->
<th class="price" style="font-size: 8px;text-align: left;">Cuota</th>
<th class="description" style="font-size: 8px;text-align: center;">Valor apostado</th>
<th class="price" style="font-size: 8px;text-align: right;">Total</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    
<tr>
  <!--<td><?= $categoria; ?></td>
  <td><?= $local; ?> vs <?= $visitante; ?></td>-->
  <td style="font-size: 8px;">2.5</td>
  <td style="font-size: 8px;text-align: center;">10</td>
  <td style="font-size: 8px;text-align: right;">25</td>
  
 </tr>
 
 </tbody>

</table>
</div>

<!--SEGUNDA ITERACIÓN -->


<div class="table-responsive">

  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="description" style="text-align:left;">Ganancia total</td>
  <td class="description" style="text-align:right;">750 PEN</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

</div>
<div class="table-responsive centered">
 
 
<!--</div>-->
<!--<div class="table-responsive">-->
 <table class="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
    

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><p style="font-size: 7px;">El monto maximo a pagar es de S/20000.00 . La cuota maximo a pagar es de 1000
Prohibido para menores de edad. revise su jugada. Sin ticket no se paga. Jugadas de futbol validas hasta el pitazo final del segundo tiempo. Jugadas con errores evidentes y/o fuera de horario seran anuladas. El ticket caduca a los 7 dias. Acepto el reglamento descrito en F0rbet.com</p>
    </td>  
 </tr>
 </tbody>

</table>   
</div>  
            
        </div>

        <button id="btnPrint" class="hidden-print">Imprimir</button>
        <script src="assets/css/imprimir/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu problema no tiene relación con PHP, debes eliminar la etiqueta y agregar un [MRE] que no depende ni de PHP ni de la base de datos

Comment: Listo,modificada

Comment: Vale !! Ahora me queda la duda: Cuando dices `borde` lo que quieres es que todo el texto esté dentro de rectángulo ??

Comment: @Yussef correcto caballero